# Require child of abstract class to not override method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

With python abstract classes, is there a way to require that a class instance does not override a particular method?

Using the `@abstractmethod` decorator on a method requires the child class to define the method. Skipping the `@abstractmethod` decorator allows the child to skip defining the method and "silently inherent" the abstract method. What I'd like is something like a `@onlyabstractmethod` to decorate a method that I want to ensure the child does not override.